# Visual studio 2017 Angular material intellisense and code snippets

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, intellisense

I am unable to view the 'Intellisense' for angular material components in html in visual studio 2017.do I need do any additional configurations/setup?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean Angular and not AngularJS...

The answer is no you don't need anything else as its not currently possible. It was previously possible when Microsoft implemented intellisense using .ngml files in a previous VS2017 version, but they never then updated it to work on .html files (which is your only option if you are using the Angular CLI to create your app).

I've also tried the (current) preview of Visual Studio 2019 and it's not implemented there either unfortunately, don't know if it will be. There doesn't seem to be much 'push' from people to get Microsoft to (re)implement it apart from a few requests here and there, so I'm guessing either people aren't using VS2017 for their Angular stuff or they are and have just accepted there's no intellisense in the .html files...

Your only options are pretty much the following:-

1. Write your own VS extension to implement it
2. Wait for Microsoft to implement it
3. Don't use the Angular CLI and instead construct your app with webpack where you can configure everything yourself (not recommended)
4. Use another editor such as Visual Studio Code for your Angular stuff where the Angular intellisense works (personally I do this with VS2017 for my .NET core API and VSCode for Angular frontend - though I wish I could just stick with VS2017 for all)
5. Use VS2017 and live without the .html file intellisense
6. Try [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) as someone stated there's Angular completion in .html files - however, I've tried it and I couldn't get it too work, plus its a paid extension...

Here's a few related links that I could find, there doesn't seem to be much...

[github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/angular2-in-visual-studio/issues)
[visual studio developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/351164/intellisense-for-angular-2-templates.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and detailed description.
As you said, I am working on latest  angular 7 version. 

I will  wait for Microsoft to implement and if required will  check Visual studio code.
On a different note, just want  to ask a question. 
How .net core web  angular template project is different from creating  two projects, one  pure angular project and  another .net core api project?

Comment: Thanks I think its in one project to make things a little easier than having two separate projects that both need configuration. So for example, you could start debugging your .net core API project but if you've not configured your client side (e.g. ng serve) project to be running at the same time then you'll not be able to access your site as there's only an API running. If you look at the single template project .csproj file it has MSBuild commands to start the client side automatically via ng serve and you get a whole site running instead of just front or back end. Just my two cents...

Comment: For the Angular part of the .Net core project, use VS code. It has an extension called [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template)

Comment: @Karthik, unfortunately the Angular Language Service is not working 100% in html files, for example custom directives don't show up and when binding for example routerLink without brackets.